# How to add glare effect to a object in volumetrics?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, volumetrics

Hey guys I need your help!! I want to add the glare effect (fog glow) while volumetrics is turned on in world tab but unfortunately I am not able to do so. [image][image]